# Why $|0\rangle \langle 0|=\frac {1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}|0_j\rangle \langle 0_j|\bigotimes \mathbb {I}_{\overline j}$ in VQLS

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, entanglement

I am having some trouble to derive equation In paper [Variational Quantum Linear Solver](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.05820.pdf)

1. $|0\rangle \langle 0|=\frac {1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}|0_j\rangle \langle 0_j|\bigotimes \mathbb {I}_{\overline j}$
2. $|0_j\rangle \langle 0_j|=(\mathbb{I}_j + Z_j)/2$
3. $\delta_{ll^\prime}^{(j)}=\beta_{ll^\prime} +\langle0| V^\dagger A_{l^\prime}^\dagger U Z_j \otimes \mathbb{I}_{\bar j}U^\dagger A_lV|0 \rangle$

Any tips to showing if there is an advantage or not would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. The first one is not true, but it doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the paper. However, the expression on the right hand side has $|0...0\rangle$ as its unique $+1$ eigenstate, while also being a local operator. Highly-nonlocal operators like $|0...0\rangle \langle 0...0 |$ appear to be unwieldy for variational algorithms.
2. This can be proven by inspection: $| 0_j \rangle \langle  0_j |$ is equal to a tensor product of $\mathbb{I}_1 \otimes ... \otimes \mathbb{I}_{j-1}$, $|0 \rangle \langle 0 |$, and $\mathbb{I}_{j+1} \otimes ... \otimes \mathbb{I}_{n}$. The middle term is a 2x2 matrix
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   which is equal to the sum of identity matrix and Pauli $Z$ matrix, divided by two.
3. This follows if we use (2).

Comment: Hi @Alexey Uvarov thanks. The first one you can find in equation (7) on p.3 in paper. It used $\frac {1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}|0_j\rangle \langle 0_j|\bigotimes \mathbb {I}_{\overline j}$ instead of $| 0\rangle \langle 0|$ this come from $U| 0\rangle \langle 0|U^\dagger$. And the second answer makes me seem to understand. Thank you very much for your help.